# Beginner Educational Resources

Tags: image-processing, radar, analog-to-digital, doppler, dynamic-range-compression

New member here.  Recently got hired into a mid level EE position.  Have a BSEE but performed more radar performance analysis at a higher system level previously.  In my new group we're doing a lot of digital signal processing design, validation and verification.  I have a strong background with Matlab and am looking for educational resources on pulse doppler, pulse compression, a/d converters, FPGA design using verilog.  Appreciate any input that anyone can provide.  Thanks guys and process on.

Answer (score 1):

Any of the Stimson airborne radar books are good modern resources for general radar signal processing.

For more specific applications (basic STAP, EW, mismatched filters etc), you can look at [Mark Richard’s](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B005FQHFAM) book(s).

If your company has a library, check to see what radar books they have on hand; you may be able to get these for free.

Last, MATLAB has entire packages based around radar systems and plenty of examples that use them. If you have access to a MATLAB license, those might be good to check out as well.

Answer (score 1):

Matthew's recommendations are good, especially the Mark Richards book. This one is good in particular because it not only introduces major radar theory in general, but it also goes over how to model different phenomena and *then* how signal processing is applied to observe said phenomena. It also gives a a good treatment on the signal processing chain, everything from the antenna to sampling and calibration. Some of the more common waveforms are also described from the matched-filter (ambiguity function) point of view.

I would also recommend [Radar Systems Analysis and Design Using MATLAB](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1439884951) by Mahafza. As the title suggests, this text is accompanied by MATLAB functions and scripts as you go through the theory. Since you're versed in MATLAB, this would be a great resource. In addition to that, MathWorks has quite a few articles on radar topics.

Answer (score 0):

I may be biased, but I think this course offered by the IEEE is fantastic! (Disclaimer: I teach this course). Next one is coming up in May 2021 (but offered routinely) with prerecorded video combined with live Q&A workshops and is the fast track to learning DSP.

http://ieeeboston.org/event/digital-signal-processing-webinar/